# '90s space prison escape movie with freezing trap scene

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm on a mission to find a movie from the '90s that fits this description.

It's set in space, possibly with space prisoners. Our main character, a man, leads a group of soldiers or ex-convicts attempting a daring escape. I believe the protagonist might resemble a young Arnold Schwarzenegger.

The scene I remember takes place in a hallway with traps. One of these traps freezes anyone who breathes or opens their eyes. The main character is able to go through the trap but one of his companions slips up, opens their eyes, and gets frozen. The pursuers are likely outfitted in special suits.

The trap itself is like gelatin, hindering swift movement. I believe the movie was made in the late '80s or '90s

Comment: I don't remember a gelatinous trap, but the first movie that comes to mind is [Fortress 2: Re-Entry](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0179183/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0_tt_8_nm_0_q_fortress%25202) from 2000. Christopher Lambert as the protagonist, and I can't say I see any particular resemblance to Arnold Schwarzenegger. It does take place in a prison in space and the movie has a B ring to it, but other than that, I'm very uncertain, which is why I'm not posting this as an answer, but it's worth mentioning.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the check mark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is ***[Spoiler](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120187/)*** (1998).

> When an innocent man is sent to the toughest penal colony in the universe, he vows to escape, return to Earth and be reunited with the daughter he was forced to leave behind.

The protagonist, Roger Mason, is played by [Gary Daniels](https://en.notrecinema.com/communaute/stars/stars.php3?staridx=34837), who was pretty muscular at the time and could therefore be seen as resembling a young Arnie.

> [image: Image of Roger Mason from the film, "Spoiler" (1998).]
>
> <sub>*Spoiler* (1998)</sub>

Mason is incarcerated within a prison located not in space, but in a futuristic version of New York. He escapes several times in order to see his daughter, but keeps getting caught on the outside and sent back to prison before he can reach her.

During one of his breakouts, a few other inmates tag along with him, and they have to pass through a corridor containing a security measure known as Deep Shadow, described thusly:

> MASON: It's Deep Shadow.
>
> PHIL: How long is it?
>
> MASON: Thirty... maybe forty feet.
>
> RENNY: What is a 'Deep Shadow?'
>
> PHIL: **Atmospheric glacier. Freezes all moisture instantly. You open your eyes and they're ice cubes. You inhale and your lungs freeze rock solid, like that.**
>
> RENNY: Then what the fuck are we supposed to do now?
>
> MASON: Close your eyes and hold your breath; what do you think?
>
> <sub>*Spoiler* (1998)</sub>

Mason and one other inmate make it through the corridor -- covered in frost, but otherwise okay -- but another inmate loses his way, opens his eyes, and breaks apart into tiny frozen fragments. Some prison guards give chase wearing helmets and gas masks, and are able to run through the corridor with no problem.

As the characters run through the corridor, the visuals are distorted and their movements are slowed, almost like they're running underwater, except that you can see snow falling around them.

Some brief shots of the corridor in question are visible from around the 1:29 mark onward in the trailer below.